# How to request new tiles in TileLayer (React Leaflet) every 30min?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, mapbox

This is what I have:

```
const RL = require('react-leaflet');
var Map = RL.Map;
var TileLayer = RL.TileLayer;

<Map
  zoom={14}
  zoomSnap={0}
  style={{height: "100%"}}
  ref={(map) => { this.map = map; }}
>
  <TileLayer url={`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/${process.env.MAPBOX_URL}/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?fresh=true&access_token=${process.env.MAPBOX_API}`}/>
```

But I can't figure out how to request new tiles every 30min? I need that to show updated traffic information...

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to re-render the component that includes `Map` and `TileLayer` every 30 mins. For that, you need some sort of state in your component that will have to change every 30 mins. To schedule the updates, `setInterval` method is the way to go.

Being said that, let's assume your component is called `Parent` and let's scaffold it:

```
class Parent extends Component {

  state = {
    updatesCount: 0
  };

  intervalId = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.update, 1800000) // every 30 mins
  }

  update = () => {
     // this function will be called every 30 mins, updating the state and causing the component to re-render
     this.setState({ updatesCount: this.state.updatesCount++ });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <Map
        zoom={14}
        zoomSnap={0}
        style={{height: "100%"}}
        ref={(map) => { this.map = map; }}
      >
        <TileLayer url={`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/${process.env.MAPBOX_URL}/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?fresh=true&access_token=${process.env.MAPBOX_API}`}/>
    </div>
  }


}
```